# Bulkifying a trigger with a fiscal year/quarter specification

Tags: apex, trigger

Please, give me a hint about how to approach the problem.

### Problem

Every first Event based on StartDate in a Fiscal year and quarter should have the FirstEvent__c boolean field set to TRUE, other Event records should have it set to FALSE.

Example fiscal quarters:

- 1/1/2021 - 3/31/2021 - first quarter of year 2021
- 4/1/2021 - 6/30/2021 - second quarter of year 2021
- 7/1/2021 - 9/30/2021 - third quarter of year 2021
- 10/1/2021 - 12/31/2021 - fourth quarter of year 2022
- 1/1/2021 - 3/31/2022 - first quarter of year 2022
- 4/1/2021 - 6/30/2022 - second quarter of year 2022
- 7/1/2021 - 9/30/2022 - third quarter of year 2022
- 10/1/2021 - 12/31/2022 - fourth quarter of year 2022

So if we had 1000 events in a database, every event which starts the first in a given quarter of a given year should be flagged as FirstEvent__c, other Event records should be false.

Is there a way to avoid a SOQL in a for loop just like this?

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert, after update) {

    List<Event> updates = new List<Event>();
    
    for(Event e1 : trigger.new){
        Integer year = e1.StartDateTime.year();
        Integer quarter = (e1.StartDateTime.month() / 3.0).round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING).intValue();
    
        List <Event> events = [SELECT id, FirstEvent__c FROM Event WHERE CALENDAR_YEAR = :year AND CALENDAR_MONTH = :quarter ORDER BY StartDateTime];
    
        Boolean first = true;

        for(Event e2 : events){
            if(first){
                e2.FirstEvent__c = true;
                first = false;
            } else {
                e2.FirstEvent__c = false;
            }
            updates.add(e2);
         }
    }  
    update updates;
}
```

Comment: @dbae1   i think  going incremental way will be more optimal. in current case  you will go through every event  of org  which is not fesible.  please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even  if we can ut first event  query outide of for loop ,  you will still face issue  in case of large data  volumes if soql  return more thn 50k records.

with your current approach  you will iterate  over complete events in  your org based on quarter and year   which is very resource intensive.

**Why not do it in incremental  manner.**
There can be 2 scenarios:

1. you have  firstevent  for given  quarter  and year
   ->  then compare all trigger records  with first event  and keep on storing latest first event
2. you do not have  any event  for quarter year
   ->  make first trigger  record first event  nd compare  remaining event  as per 1.

please  go through  this code for  increment  comparison and updating first event.
in case  you want to go  through your approach   for comparing every event  then batch class is more feasible not trigger.

```
trigger EventTrigger on Event (after insert, after update) {
    //final list to update
    List<Event> updates = new List<Event>();
    // list to hold previous first event  which  will be updated to false if first event is true
    List<Event> EventToUpdateFEFalse  =  new List<Event>();
    
    Map<String,Event> firstEventMapByQuarterYear = new Map<String,Event>();
    // iterate  already exisiting first  event and store in map  by quarter-year 
    // this map  will keep on updating first event  for particular quarter year based on startdatetime comparison   
    for(Event e : [SELECT id, FirstEvent__c,startDateTime FROM Event where FirstEvent__c = true] ) 
    {
       firstEventMapByQuarterYear.put(String.valueof(e.StartDateTime.year()) + '-'  + String.valueof((e.StartDateTime.month() / 3.0).round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING).intValue()) , e); 
     
    
    }
    
    for(Event e1 : trigger.new){
        Integer year = e1.StartDateTime.year();
        Integer quarter = (e1.StartDateTime.month() / 3.0).round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING).intValue();
        // if  there are  no event for particular year  put  current event in map.
        if(  !firstEventMapByQuarterYear.containskey(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter)))
        {
                     firstEventMapByQuarterYear.put(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter) , e1);
        }
         // if there is first event  compare  startdatetime  and update  first event accordingly
        if( firstEventMapByQuarterYear.containskey(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter))
           && e1.startdatetime <  firstEventMapByQuarterYear.get(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter)).startdatetime)
           {
             EventToUpdateFEFalse.add(firstEventMapByQuarterYear.get(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter) ));
             firstEventMapByQuarterYear.put(String.valueof(year) + '-' + String.valueof(quarter) , e1);

            }
        
         }
         
         
    // loop through all first events and make first_event__c true 
    for(Event e : firstEventMapByQuarterYear.values())
    {
      if( e.FirstEvent__c == false)
      {
      
      updates.add(new Event(id = e.Id , FirstEvent__c = true ));
      }
    
    
    }
    
        // loop through all previous first events and make first_event__c false 

    for(Event e : EventToUpdateFEFalse)
    {
       if(e.FirstEvent__c == true)
       {
          updates.add(new Event(id = e.Id , FirstEvent__c = false ));

       }
    
    }
    
    
    update  updates;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed a better solution.

Comment: Although when I think about it, this does not work in case there are data inconsistencies in the database. For example all event records have the flag FirstEvent__c marked as FALSE. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: before implementing trigger  ,  yes  there   would be data  inconstintencies .    you need to do calculation of first event   in excel  and  update first event records.    you can  also   implement  a batch  class   for  such   issues   which can be run as and when required   but  definitely   it is  not  something   you want   to do   on every   updte/insert.    additional   question :   can event be deleted?   if yes  ,  you would also want to  handle that  logic

Comment: Okay, I'll implement a batch class then. I'll try coding something then I'll probably post again. Thanks a lot

Comment: sure   but try  to keep  batch class   option  when  you need to resolve data  inconstintencies   as   you would   be analayzing   your complete  event data   .incremental logic  should work fine  if existing data   is fine.   and   please also check   if you would need logic for delete   also.  in case of delete  ,   if deleted   event is first   event    you need  a logic to make next  available event   first event  for   that quarter  year.    Thanks